# Simple mathematic operastions leads to 1=2

Tags: mathematics

Consider $a$ and $b$ are equals. We do some basic mathematics operations ( add, subtract, multiple, and divide) on them. This ends to $2=1$. Where is the problem ?

$$
\require{cancel}
a=b \\
a*a=b*a  \\
a^2 = ba  \\
a^2 - b^2 = ba - b^2 \\
(a-b)(a+b) = b (a-b) \\
\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{(a-b)} = \frac{b(a-b)}{(a-b)}  \\
\frac{\cancel{(a-b)}(a+b)}{\cancel{(a-b)}} = \frac{b\cancel{(a-b)}}{\cancel{(a-b)}}  \\
a+b = b  \\
a+ a = a  \\
2a = a \\
2=1 \\
$$

PS: This is my first puzzle here ! Hope it is ok :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a duplicate of an already existing question. (I appreciate the effort, though!)

Comment: @Deusovi I searched before post but could not find duplicate ! Thanks.